# Add a Behavior to an Image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

In my program I have an System.Controls.Image to which I want
to add a shaking Behavior from here [Animate Image in button to shake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093302/how-to-animate-an-image-in-a-button-to-shake-every-30-seconds-in-wpf)

I copied the ShakingBehavior to my project to it's own class,
and I already have the Blend SDK.

Now I added the XAML Part to my Image

```
<Image Source="myImage.png" Grid.Row="{Binding Path=Row}" Grid.Column="{Binding Path=Col}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ShakeBehavior RepeatInterval="5" SpeedRatio="3.0"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

</Image>
```

Now I get an error that I cannot get rid of!

(As I do not have an english VS here, I try to translate the message)

> The Interaction type has no attachable Behaviors property

probably just a namespace to add (the i alias), but I cannot bring it to work

**edit** 
More information: The Image is contained in a button, which is inside a datatemplate.

And (at best) I want to start the animation when another button in the view is clicked.
(this Behavior shall help to find the button as a hint)

Comment: HAVE YOU ADDDED THE using tags in the beginning?

Comment: Have u added a refrence to System.Windows.Interactivity.dll and added this namespace in ur xaml xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestResizeBehavior"

Comment: The project compiles good, the usings in the behavior are included, it's just the XAML part left, which I do not accomplish.

Comment: @Mohit I already referenced the Interactivity.dll. Local is my own namespace here. Now i added that i: clr-namespace, but I get a different error stating "unknown build error, index based on 0 must be greater or equal to null and less than the size of the argument list". The old "no attachable property" error is still there after rebuild.

Comment: @Mohit: Oh no! There was an not printed special character in your answer (which i saw after trying to give more information to my question and copied the xaml again). Now i see the animation! Please wrap up your comment as answer, so that I can accept it. Perhaps you have information for me on how to control the animation from outside, for example on a button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Mohib doesn't want to, i will post the correct line that I have missed:

this one should be without those magic unprinted values that can be found in Mohibs answer.

xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"