# Switch on animation on Image from ViewModel 

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, mvvm

After getting the animation on an image to run 
which I got from here: [Animate image in a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093302/how-to-animate-an-image-in-a-button-to-shake-every-30-seconds-in-wpf?lq=1)
I want to be able to switch the animation on and off, depending
on a button click from outside, i.e. from the ViewModel

So I added a new DependencyProperty to the Bahavior (with all those things that are needed here)

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty IsShakingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(IsShakingName,
                                    typeof(bool),
                                    typeof(ShakeBehavior),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(DefaultIsShaking));
```

I have added a new public property to my ViewModel

```
public bool IsShaking { get; set; }
```

But what can I do to switch the animation on and off, depending on the
ViewModel property set to true or false? (I want to control the animation
on a button click)

Here is some of the code of which i think it is relevant

```
private Timeline CreateAnimationTimeline()
{
    DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames animation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

    animation.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath("(0).(1)", UIElement.RenderTransformProperty, RotateTransform.AngleProperty));

    int keyFrameCount = 8;
    double timeOffsetInSeconds = 0.25;
    double totalAnimationLength = keyFrameCount * timeOffsetInSeconds;
    double repeatInterval = RepeatInterval;
    bool isShaking = IsShaking;

    // Can't be less than zero and pointless to be less than total length
    if (repeatInterval < totalAnimationLength)
        repeatInterval = totalAnimationLength;

    animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(repeatInterval));

    int targetValue = 12;
    for (int i = 0; i < keyFrameCount; i++)
        animation.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(i % 2 == 0 ? targetValue : -targetValue, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i * timeOffsetInSeconds))));

    animation.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(0, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalAnimationLength))));
    return animation;
}
```

Here is the part of my XAML:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Focusable="False" Command="{Binding ClickToolCommand}" Grid.Row="{Binding Path=Row}" Grid.Column="{Binding Path=Col}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
                        <Image Source="myImage.png" Grid.Row="{Binding Path=Row}" Grid.Column="{Binding Path=Col}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <local:ShakeBehavior RepeatInterval="1" SpeedRatio="3.0" IsShaking="{Binding Path=IsShaking}"/>
                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                        </Image>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Perhaps a DataTrigger can help, as pointed out in other SOs, but I do not have a storyboard inside my XAML, as I have a custom `Behavior`

Any input highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, let me repeat what I said in the original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093302/how-to-animate-an-image-in-a-button-to-shake-every-30-seconds-in-wpf) that started this whole thing.  Doing a "shaky" image button becomes a whole lot simpler if you just use a custom control.  Also, using a shaky image button as "a way to engage a users attention" is a horrible idea that reminds me of 1990's website design.  In addition, there is a small flaw in the implementation you copied,  there is no exit action on the trigger that was created. Regardless, here is how to do what you require:

Create an attached property as follows:

```
        public static bool GetStopAnimating(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(StopAnimatingProperty);
        }

        public static void SetStopAnimating(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(StopAnimatingProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StopAnimating.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StopAnimatingProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("StopAnimating", typeof(bool), typeof(ShakeBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
```

Then replace the existing "OnAttach" method with the folllowing:

```
        private BeginStoryboard _beginStoryBoard;
        private RemoveStoryboard _removeStoryboard;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            _orignalStyle = AssociatedObject.Style;

            _beginStoryBoard = new BeginStoryboard { Storyboard = CreateStoryboard() };
            _beginStoryBoard.Name = "terribleUi";
            _removeStoryboard = new RemoveStoryboard();
            _removeStoryboard.BeginStoryboardName = _beginStoryBoard.Name; 

            AssociatedObject.Style = CreateShakeStyle();

            AssociatedObject.Style.RegisterName("terribleUi", _beginStoryBoard);
        }
```

Then instead of having the shaking trigger based off the visibility of the button, change it to work off your attached property:

```
        private Trigger CreateTrigger()
        {
            Trigger trigger = new Trigger
            {
                Property = StopAnimatingProperty,
                Value = false,
            };

            trigger.EnterActions.Add(_beginStoryBoard);

            trigger.ExitActions.Add(_removeStoryboard);

            return trigger;
        }
```

Then you use it as follows:

```
<Button Height="50" Width="150" >
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="\Untitled.png" local:ShakeBehavior.StopAnimating="{Binding YourPropertyToStopTheShaking}">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <local:ShakeBehavior RepeatInterval="5.0" SpeedRatio="3.0"  />
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Image>

        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

Comment: But here are some questions left: Do you have an iPhone? What would you recommend to highlight an element?